# Creating reclass-rules-textfile within Simple Python Editor of GRASS GIS

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass.script

We are writing a script with the simple Python editor (GRASS GIS).
We try to set the rules for a reclass command within the script (without creating a txt.file manually).

Is it possible to set the rules within the script or is it possible to create a txt.file with the simple Python editor?

Comment: Have you tried using Python functions to write your text file?  This sounds like something you should research at [so] rather than ask here.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at existing Python code in the main GRASS GIS repository, for example here:

https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/scripts/r.reclass.area/r.reclass.area.py#L139

Here, the output of one command is used to generate the rules file.